# What is this topological space homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space

$$ \zeta= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}^\infty \bigg\{(x,y)\in(0,1)^2\big|\log(x)\log(y)=n\bigg\} $$

endowed with the subspace topology of $\Bbb R^2.$

> What is $\zeta$ homeomorphic to?

I think it might be homeomorphic to the union of a countable family of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: Your notation is odd. It should be $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}$ or $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n =0}^\infty $.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio No, it doesn't, since there's no pair $(x,y)\in (0,1)^2$ such that $\log(x)\log(y)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions $$F:\Bbb N_+\times(-\infty,0)\to \zeta\\ F(n,t)=(e^t,e^{n/t})\\ G:\zeta\to\Bbb N_+\times(-\infty,0)\\ G(x,y)=(\log x\log y,\log x)$$

These maps are continuous such that $F\circ G=id_\zeta$ and $G\circ F=id_{\Bbb N_+\times (-\infty,0)}$.